# Detecting location with GPS, but no cellular network

Tags: android, location, android-gps

How can I detect the location in an Android app when there is only wifi + GPS available, but no network signal?

Currently, app requests for coarse and fine location permission. but it doesn't detect the location of the user without cellular network.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro ?

Comment: GPS does not require the cellular network, but the rough location from cellular network helps finding the GPS location faster. (By using the so called "A-GPS", "Assisted GPS") So without the cellular network getting the GPS fix might just take some time. And of course it might only work outdoors or at least close to a window when inside. Many tablets without the cellular modem do have GPS and they work too.

Comment: did you try with google fused api ?